# How to translate git-clone-command to clone-uri

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I try to import a [git project](https://mina.apache.org/vysper-project/sources.html) into eclipse. The handbook is telling me to use this command in the console:

```
git clone http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/mina-vysper.git vysper
```

Unfortunately i use git via eclipse and if i import from uri eclipse telling me the url is not a valid clone-uri:

[image: Eclipse screenshot of invalid clone-uri]

How to translate the git command to a clone-uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the error log you will notice that the reason of the Transport Error is : `301 Moved Permanently` . So the repository is not there anymore, try with this URI instead : `git://git.apache.org/vysper.git`

Comment: Looks like a bug, isnt it?

Comment: A bug on which side ? I've tried cloning your original URL and I'm getting nothing apart an error of : Operation timed out.

Comment: A bug in eclipse. Should the 301 not have been followed?

Comment: Yes, it should be, but in this case, the operation timeout anyway, so we should test it a little bit more and then eventually open a bug.